# i have CrystalReportViewer run in blank page i can't go next page?

Tags: crystal-reports

i used this code for Redirect to blank page

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('Show_Report_Goods.aspx', '_blank','location=0');</script>");
```

how fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Where Did you use this code, maybe you used this code in Page Postback it does not work in page post back.
try it some where else....